# jquery - contents or ajax -getting external webpage and filtering it

Tags: jquery, iframe, external

I want to get an external webpage (on a different server/url) of mine and filter and then filter out the content so I just return all the html between the #content div and then insert it into #newcontent of my current div.

do far I have tried

```
 <iframe src="http://www.myurl.com" width="80%" height="600" id='frameDemo'></iframe>
 <script>$("#frameDemo").contents().find("a").css("background-color","#BADA55");</script>
```

Comment: $("#frameDemo").contents().find("a").css("background-color","red"); #framedemo is an iframe   <iframe src="http://www.myurl.com" width="80%" height="600" id='frameDemo'></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

If it's on a different server you can't do that with javascript/jquery i think (you could use jsonp for making cross domain calls but this is different).
What you could do is send the link to your server with ajax, let you server get the page (with cUrl for example), process it and then echo back to your page a json with the result.